# Palette is not available in Jboss Developer Studio

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, jboss-developer-studio

I want to create a sample project to demo Camel routes working with message communication/transformation between two applications. But when I move to palette to create the routes for CamelContext.xml file , I don't find any palette item.
I tried to search how I can get palette install into my Red Hat Jboss developer studio, but no luck.

Please suggest.

Comment: Just to be sure, you have installed JBoss Developer Studio, and if so what is the version you use. I think the Camel tooling is only included out of the box in the very latest release. In older versions you need to install that on top of the developer studio.

Comment: I am using Version: 11.0.0.GA, which I guess is latest available.

Comment: Update: I am able to see the Palette items now.
What I did: I created a new Fuse Integration Project with Project Type as "Spring DSL"  , previously I was creating "Bluprint DSL" type Project. -->Interestingly the palette now shows for both kind of projects.

**BUT: **now I am not able to add items from palette into my camel-Context.xml file , it does not allow it to edit when I drag any item from palette, any solution to that ?-->

NOTE: I am new to Jboss Fuse, so I might be missing some simple configuration here , please help.

Comment: Which precise Camel components have you tried to create?

Comment: In which container have you tried to drag-n-drop them? Inside the Route? or outside?
Do you have any error in Eclipse log after Drag-n-drop? You can have a look at it Windows -> Show View -> Other -> Error Log

Comment: Got it, I was directly putting any component into blank space, I tried putting Routes and in that I put file component , and it worked. I will explore these more now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Note this will only work if you are working or starting a new Camel project.

Here is some notes on how to show the palette window.

- Make sure you have your camel blueprint or spring file selected. As far as I know this will only work for XML DSL. The screenshot below shows the file I am talking about it is normally found under camel contexts. Make sure this opened in the editor by double clicking on it. You should have a visual representation of your camel route on screen.

[image]

- To show the palette you can active it by using the menu options Windows -> Show View -> Other. Under the general tab you will find Palette. Double click it and open it. The screenshot below shows you what you should see.

[image]